# how to remove seams in a stitched panoramic image?

Tags: matlab

I have implemented image stitching process in matlab and want to remove the seams that are present in the final canvas i.e my output. Can anyone please suggest some methods...

Answer (score 1):

Use the mincut algorithm from Image Quilting by Efros and Freeman.  [Code here](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~cdecoro/imagequilting/)